# How to convert List<Model> to complex response type?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

```
    Public Class Employee
{
   Public String EmployeeId {get;set;}
   Public String EmployeeName {get;set;}
   Public String Department {get;set;}
}

Public Class Department
{
   Public String DepartmentId {get;set;}
   Public String DepartmentName {get;set;}
   Public String Address {get;set;}
}

Public Class Address
{
   Public String AddrOne {get;set;}
   Public String City {get;set;}
}
```

I have 3 models, List, List and List
Post execution of procedure, above mentioned 3 models should get populate with List, List and List
and I have to return the data in below format...

What is the best approach to get response in below format ?

```
<Employees>
 <Employee>
   <EmployeeID>   </EmployeeID>
   <EmployeeName>   </EmployeeName>
   <Department>
     <DepartmentID>     </DepartmentID>
     <DepartmentName>     </DepartmentName>
    <Address>
      <Addr1>   </Addr1>
          <City>    </City>
    </Address>
   <Department>
 </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Comment: [XML serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @AfnanAhmad , I am looping though all 3 collections (Employee, Department and Address)  based on their hierarchy and creating the xml structure.
I believe there is a better way of doing this... but do not have any clue

forrach(DataRow drEmp in ...)
{
  xmlElement.Add(EmpID)
  xmlElement.Add(EmpNAme)
   forrach(DataRow drEmp in ...)
    {   
        xmlElement.Add(DeptID) 
        xmlElement.Add(DeptName) 

       forrach(DataRow drEmp in ...)
        {   
           xmlElement.Add(Addr1)   
        }
     }
}

Answer (score 1):

You could create the following classes:

```
public class Model
{
   public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
   public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
   public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
   public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
   public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
   public string DepartmentName {get; set; }
   public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
   public string AddrOne { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Next you can create an instance of the model and populate with data and serialize it as XML

Answer (score 0):

XML-Serialization:

Create a CollectionClass and add Methods to serialize it:

```
public class MyCollection
{
    public List<Employee> = new List<Employee>();
    public List<Department> = new List<Department>();
    public List<Address> = new List<Address>();

    public string ToXML()
    {
        var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, this);
        return stringwriter.ToString();
    }

    // You have to use your Class-Type here 3 times
    public static MyCollection LoadFromXML(string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyCollection));
            return serializer.Deserialize(streamReader) as MyCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can save your class as xml-File:

```
        MyCollection myCollection = new MyCollection();
        //Now add your entries, myCollection.Add(new Department(....));  

        //Save your class as xml-File
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\MyClass.xml", myCollection.ToXML());
```

And then you can load it:

```
        //Load your class
        MyCollection myCollection = MyCollection.LoadFromXML("C:\\MyClass.xml");
```

EDIT: Changed it to a CollectionClass-Sample, which should fit your situation